# android - How to show BottomSheetDialog from a fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

Im working on an app which has a Fragment containing the widget Toolbar and a Recyclerview. The fragment is a CoordinatorLayout.

I need to call my BottomSheetDrawer on Navigation button click. Since my Toolbar is inside a fragment, i need to show the BottomSheetDrawer trough there.

I tried implementing the function the same way as Activity, however it doesnt work, because supportFragmentManager is flagged as an unresolved reference.

**What's the correct way to show a BottomSheetFragment from a fragment?**

**Fragment.kt**

```
class FragmentTrack : Fragment() {
    
    ...

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        topToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            val dialog = FragmentBottomSheetDrawer()
            dialog.show(supportFragmentManager, dialog.tag)

        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent to `supportFragmentManager` in a Fragment is `childFragmentManager`. That is the correct FragmentManager to use for any kind of `DialogFragment`.

Comment: Using ```childFragmentManager``` makes the app crash without any log in the Logcat...

Comment: Crashes will always have a stack trace

Comment: Had to connect physical device to get logcat, my bad. Here's whats wrong:
```java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference```

Comment: Well, your Fragment's view isn't going to be created until `onViewCreated()`, so if `topToolbar` is part of your Fragment's layout, then `onCreate()` is too early. (I'll also note you should never use `retainInstance` for any Fragment with a UI).

Comment: I might have been doing something wrong with ID's then. I've updated the question putting the coordinator fragment xml too. The app still crashes with the same logcat error, but again, it might be ID's naming fault

Comment: So is `topToolbar` part of your Fragment or part of your Activity? You can't use Kotlin synthetic properties from your Activity in your Fragment

Comment: Your problems seem to have less to do with actually starting the bottom sheet dialog (which, if you attached it to a button in your fragment, would work just fine with `childFragmentManager` and more with a completely different problem with accessing your toolbar which is probably better as a completely separate question.

Comment: topToolbar is technically part of the fragment. I might've taken the wrong ID since i used the one of the Toolbar layout. However if i use the ID ```toolbar``` or ```appbar``` Android Studio flags the id used saying that supportFragmentManager is an unresolved reference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221653/discussion-between-meltix-and-ianhanniballake).